# How to set useMongoClient (Mongoose 4.11.0)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the code I use to connect to my database:

```
private connectDatabase(databaseUri: string): Promise<Mongoose.Connection> {
    return Mongoose.connect(databaseUri).then(() => {
        debug('Connected to MongoDB at %O', databaseUri);
        return Mongoose.connection;
    });
}
```

Today I updated Mongoose to version 4.11.0 and I got this warning when running my tests:

```
(node:4138) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0,
use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()`
or `createConnection()`
```

I can't find any information on how to "set useMongoClient".

Do you guys know how to?

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399

Comment: Waiting for the fix. Thanks @robertklep.

Comment: Installed 4.10.8 without issues. Please consider changing npm install mongoose --save to default to 4.10.8 until 11 is stable.

Comment: it's not ok. It fixed here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797221/connecting-to-mongo-db-with-mongoose-version-4-11-0/44798524#44798524)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Without Typescript** you can pretty much ignore the issue and use `Mongoose.connect(databaseUri, { useMongoClient: true })`.

If you really want to avoid having the warning avoid the version 4.11.0.

I updated to version 4.11.1 and since @types/mongoose@4.7.18 are not yet updated and they do not mention the field `useMongoClient` in the `ConnectionOptions`, this is how i imported the module:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

And then used this function:

```
private connectDatabase(databaseUri: string): Promise<any> {
    return Mongoose.connect(databaseUri, { useMongoClient: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connected to MongoDB at ', databaseUri);
            return Mongoose.connection;
        })
        .catch(err => debug(`Database connection error: ${err.message}`));
}
```

Answer (score 78):

This is how you use **useMongoClient**:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/advisorDemoTestDB', { useMongoClient: true })
```

Comment: vscode told me this:


Argument of type '{ useMongoClient: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: MongoError) => void'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'useMongoClient' does not exist in type '(err: MongoError) => void'.

Comment: Just saw @robertklep comment he'd left you. It seems that using useMongoClient wont work either. We'll just have to wait for that bug or rollback to 4.10.8 version for now.

Comment: I tried using `useMongoClient: true` and solved that error but all the model methods aren't working, if I use `Model.find({})` the Promise keeps pending and nothing happens.

Comment: Wait for this bug to be fix or roll back to prev version

Comment: Not sure why are people voting on this.

Comment: Voting on what?

Comment: @TiagoBértolo this is the correct answer for sure :)

Comment: works for me now in 2017. Any bugs with it must have been fixed

Answer (score 29):

Add **{ useMongoClient: true }**  as another argument to connect or createConnection method, its depends on version of mongoose you are using.

```
// Using `mongoose.connect`...
var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});
// Or `createConnection`
var promise = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});
```

Comment: What `useMongoClient` do ?

Answer (score 12):

```
mongoose.connection.openUri('mongodb://127.0.0.1/camp_v12')
```

has anyone tried this? my deprecated warning disappeared when i use this, it was from the documentation

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: It's not ok. It fixed here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797221/connecting-to-mongo-db-with-mongoose-version-4-11-0/44798524#44798524)

Answer (score 10):

The easiest fix for this would be to open your terminal, change your directory to your root project (folder where `package.json` is)

Run:
`npm remove mongoose`

then:

`npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save`

problem solved.

Upgrading is not always the best option.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: It's not a fix, it's a way to temporarily ignore the issue.

Comment: thats totally not a fix

Answer (score 6):

As many answers say, adding `{ useMongoClient: true }` in options argument to `connect` or `createConnection` method will solve the problem.

For e.g.

```
// With mongoose.connect method
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/app', { useMongoClient: true });

// With createConnection method
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/app', { useMongoClient: true });
```

**But what is MongoClient in the first place?**

From MongoDB Node.js Driver version 1.2, a new connection class MongoClient was introduced that has the same name across all the official drivers.

The new connection class **MongoClient acknowledges all writes to MongoDB**, in contrast to the existing DB connection class which has acknowledgements turned off.

So `{ useMongoClient: true }` tells moongoose to use the new connection class rather than the old one

For more info [click here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)

Answer (score 4):

Connect to MongoDB with Mongoose 4.11.x (tested with both mLab single instance and MongoDB Atlas replica set):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const options = {
  promiseLibrary: global.Promise,
  useMongoClient: true,
};

function connect() {
  mongoose.connect(URI, options)
    .then(function() {
      const admin = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db);
      admin.buildInfo(function(err, info) {
        if (err) {
          console.err(`Error getting MongoDB info: ${err}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Connection to MongoDB (version ${info.version}) opened successfully!`);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${err}`));
}

module.exports = connect;
```

Create model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `mongoose` [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client), this is how `useMongoClient` can be set.

```js
function connectDatabase(databaseUri){
    var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
        useMongoClient: true,
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix for this:

Run this command in project root folder via terminal:

`npm remove mongoose`

`npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save`

Problem solved.

Upgrading is not always the best option.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5399

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/starbucks', { 
    useMongoClient: true 
});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('openUri', function() {
    // we're connected!
});
```

Comment: Please add some description , to make answer more effective.

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

(node:1652) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`.

**Solution:** To set **useMongoClient:true** in connection property

```
var promise = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myapp', {
  useMongoClient: true,
  /* other options */
});
```

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
now listening for request

Comment: this seems totally irrelevant to the question being asked. I think it's an attempt at a self answering question. This is not the correct way to do this

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade mongoose , first you need to uninstall it with this code:

```
npm uninstall mongoose
```

Then install it again with the following code :

```
npm install mongoose  --save
```