# connecting to Mongo DB with mongoose version (4.11.0)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to access the Mongo DB with the new mongoose version (4.11.0):  "**mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app");**"

I got the following message:
*`open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or

set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`*

I tried the following fix:
"**mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app", {useMongoClient: true});**"

Conclusion: That message has disappeared, but the DB I just created has no data!

Please help!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other 
readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Deprecation warnings are just that: warnings. That "fix" is going around but it's causing more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest fix for this;

```
"npm remove mongoose"
```

then

```
"npm install mongoose@4.10.8 --save"
```

problem solved.

> Upgrading is not always the best option.

Help it will help you.

Thanks