# Mongoose model.find({}) not working after using mongoose 4.11; [Bug??]

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Mongoose model.find({}) not working after using mongoose 4.11;

I notice that mongoose is not behaving properly after updating to mongoose 4.11, after update a warning show to my screen

```
DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead
```

so I tried

```
let mongoConnectionLocal = {    
    'url': 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/image-upload-gcs'
};

mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionLocal.url, { auth:{authdb:"admin"}, useMongoClient: true},  err => { if(err) { console.log(err.stack); }});
```

Then another warning shows up

```
the options [auth] is not supported
```

so I tried,

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/image-upload-gcs?authSource=admin', { useMongoClient: true},  err => { if(err) { console.log(err.stack); }});
```

and now mongoose is not working anymore, can't even use model.find({}) or create a document

I tried reverting back to mongoose 4.10 and everything works fine. So is this a bug in mongoose 4.11 and above????

Comment: Don't use `useMongoClient: true`, it breaks your connections. Known issue with Mongoose (look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797221/connecting-to-mongo-db-with-mongoose-version-4-11-0)

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below snippet

```
  mongoose.connect(mongoConnectionLocal.url);
  const db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
  db.once('open', function callback(){
   console.log("Connection with database succeeded.");
  });
```

Comment: Ohh okay, Thanks mate. I'll definitely try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/user1';
    var promise = mongooose.connect(uri,{
        useMongoClient: true,
        });

    promise.openUri(uri,function(errr,db){
        if(errr){
            throw errr;
        }else{
            console.log("Connection Successfull");      
            mydb = db;
            
        }
    });
```

One needs to use promise for the latest version of mongoose for the database connection.You're using old method for the connection so switch over to the newer method for connection.

> [link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)