# Mongoose Query ends with no result

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to run a query to return all comments from my database through an HTTP GET request. Nothing fancy.

// controller.js

```
const indexPage = (req, res) => {
  Comment.find({})
    .exec((err, comments) => {
      if(err) res.json({error: err});
      res.json({
        message: 'This is the index page',
        comments
      });
    });
 }
```

// routes.js

`router.route('/comments')
    .get(indexPage)`

The issues is that when I visit `${HOST_NAME}/comments`, it returns nothing. I fixed this by downgrading from `4.11.0` -> `4.6.4`. I'm very curious to know if the query pattern has changed? Is there any change in the API for this release?

// model.js

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

 const commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   author: {type: String},
   message: {type: String},
 });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('Comments', commentSchema);`
```

Comment: paste your Comment model file

Comment: That's already updated @ifiok

Comment: Are you setting `useMongoClient : true` in your connection setup?

Comment: yes and that's for v4.11.0 @robertklep

Comment: @Rowland remove it and live with the deprecation warning for now, that setting is what's breaking your database queries (related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749700/how-to-set-usemongoclient-mongoose-4-11-0)

Comment: Thank you @robertklep. You can visit my question to get the context. I already have it working by downgrading to a lower version.