# findOne not executed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the code below:

```
exports.getMyPets = function (req, res){
  var email = req.body.email;
  var result = [{}];
    Owner.findOne({"email" : email }, "_id", function(err, owner){
      if(err)
        res.send(err);
        console.log("Owner: " + owner._id + "\n");
      Pet.find({"OwnerId": owner._id}, function(err, pet) {
        if(err)
          res.send(err)
          var index = pet.length;
          var empty = false;
          if(index > 0)
          empty = true;

          try{
          for (let x = 0; x < index; x += 1){

           PetPicture.findOne({"petId" : pet[x]._id}, function (err, petPic){
              console.log('pet ID: ' + pet[x]._id);
              result[x] = {
                name: pet[x].name,
                breed: pet[x].breed,
                description: pet[x].description,
                imageType: petPic.imageType,
                imageData: petPic.imageType
               };
            }); //end of petPicture.findOne
              console.log('X : ' + pet[x]._id);
          }// end of for loop
        } catch (error){
          console.log(error);
        }
        }
        while(true){
          if (result.length === index)
          break;
        }

        if(!empty){
          res.json(pet);
        } else {
          res.json(result);
        }
      }); // end of Pet,find
    }); // end of petOwner.findOne
};
```

The block of PetPicture.findOne (the whole try catch block) does not get executed when I try to call it on endpoint. It does not log anything, not even an error on the catch part. What can I do to debug this?

Comment: javascript runs in async way, convert your code to sync..

Try to use promise, to make sure your code running in sync way and get expected output

Comment: Sounds like your `mongoose.connect` is not being done properly. See [How to set useMongoClient (Mongoose 4.11.0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749700/how-to-set-usemongoclient-mongoose-4-11-0)

Comment: I wouldn't use a try/catch in this case. Are you sure `index > 0`? Also, please wrap your `if(index > 0)` correctly.

Comment: @NeilLunn My mongoose connect is fine, as it works well with my other functions on the same file.

Comment: @IsaacHinman, Yes, I'm quite sure with that.

Comment: @PRADEEPKumar Hwo do you suggest converting it to sync? Or finding a way in making this work in async mode?

Comment: Well it's unclear how your IDs are structured, but I'd recommend using `findById` instead.

Comment: if aync mode, you can use callback, else refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
and convert your code to promises